# jQuery next() function will detect wrong item sometime

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have just finished my site, you can find the problem of this page, only using phone browser.
http://easondesign.co/kayo/about-us/

the function running great at any desktop browser, but when I using iPhone safari, it will go wrong sometime.

I guess it is the problem of next(); function, the function will detect over two or three more next div, and not the next one.

is anyone can help me debug? thank you!

```js
$('.tl_next').click(function() {
  if ($('.tsli_wrap > div').last().hasClass('current')) {
    return false;
  } else {
    MoveVal += PlusMinus;;
    $('.tsli_wrap').css('transform', 'translate(0,-' + MoveVal + 'px)');
    $('.tsli_wrap > div.current')
      .removeClass('current')
      .next('div')
      .removeClass('sec')
      .addClass('current').after(function() {
        $('.tsli_wrap > div').removeClass('sec');
        $('.tsli_wrap > div.current').next().addClass('sec');
        $('.tsli_wrap > div.current').prev().addClass('sec');
      });
  }
});

$('.tl_prev').click(function() {
  if ($('.tsli_wrap > div').first().hasClass('current')) {
    return false;
  } else {
    MoveVal -= PlusMinus;;
    $('.tsli_wrap').css('transform', 'translate(0,-' + MoveVal + 'px)');
    $('.tsli_wrap > div.current')
      .removeClass('current')
      .prev('div')
      .removeClass('sec')
      .addClass('current').after(function() {
        $('.tsli_wrap > div').removeClass('sec');
        $('.tsli_wrap > div.current').next().addClass('sec');
        $('.tsli_wrap > div.current').prev().addClass('sec');
      });
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="tl_arrow">
  <div class="tl_prev">
    <svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 16.7 12.2" style="enable-background:new 0 0 16.7 12.2;" xml:space="preserve">
          <polyline class="tl_line" points="1.9,10.8 8.4,2 14.8,10.8 "/>
         </svg>
  </div>
  <div class="tl_next">
    <svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 16.7 12.2" style="enable-background:new 0 0 16.7 12.2;" xml:space="preserve">
         <polyline class="tl_line" points="14.8,2 8.4,10.8 1.9,2 "/>
         </svg>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="tl_slider">
  <div class="tsli_wrap">
    <div>
      <i></i>
      <span>2018</span>
      <p>The first successful exhibition in LAS VEGAS</p>
    </div>
    <div>
      <i></i>
      <span>2017</span>
      <p>The first successful exhibition in LAS VEGAS first successful exhibition</p>
    </div>
    <div>
      <i></i>
      <span>2016</span>
      <p>The first successful exhibition in LAS VEGAS</p>
    </div>
    <div>
      <i></i>
      <span>2015</span>
      <p>The first successful exhibition in LAS VEGAS</p>
    </div>
    <div>
      <i></i>
      <span>2014</span>
      <p>The first successful exhibition in LAS VEGAS</p>
    </div>
    <div>
      <i></i>
      <span>2013</span>
      <p>The first successful exhibition in LAS VEGAS</p>
    </div>
    <div>
      <i></i>
      <span>2012</span>
      <p>The first successful exhibition in LAS VEGAS</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: If we should help you debug, you should really provide a working example of the problem, since it's that we have to start with fixing the snippet before we can even start testing it.

Comment: I'm doubtful about your use of `.after()` having a function as argument... The function should return an element... [Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/after/#passing-a-function) -- It doesn't look like it. I'm too tired to test your code, but I can say it looks real strange.

Comment: Hi Thank you for your reply, sorry about code not clearly, I found the reason, because I put into on
$(document).ready, and $(document).on('load, resize', function)
 , maybe iPhone used code twice so next function did twice get wrong next object.
when I moved the code to document ready only, the function doing well.
but I still need this can be active at on load and resize same time...

Thanks Louys remind, i changed .after() to .queue(), are also works fine.